# Turn off type conversion in clang

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, type-conversion, clang++

I am migrating a legacy code from gcc to clang. There are a lot of type conversion issue in the code i.e. arithmetic operation on void pointer, const char* to char* conversion, unsigned char* to char* conversion,assigning parent class object to child class. Since code base is very large, it will be very cumbersome task to typecast everything.
Is there any(or set of) flag(s) using which I can turn off these error? I have tried -fpermissive or -Wno-error-(error type).

```
char*  Page::pageTitle()
{

    jvalue pageObject;

    m_javaClass.CallMethod(
        m_javaObject.Get(),
        "getPageTitle",
        "()Ljava/lang/String;",
        'L',
        (jvalue*)0,
        &pageObject );

    if (pageObject.l == NULL)
        return NULL;

    JNIEnv* env = JNIGetEnv();
    jboolean isCopy = JNI_TRUE;

    const char* pageString = env->GetStringUTFChars(pageObject.l, &isCopy);

    return pageString;
}

error: cannot initialise a parameter of type 'jstring' (aka '_jstring *') with an lvalue of type 'jobject' (aka '_jobject *')
```

jvalue.l is jobject type and GetStringUTFChars is declared as `const char* GetStringUTFChars(jstring string, jboolean* isCopy)` in jni.h
and _jstring is declared as

```
class _jstring : public _jobject {}
```

So we are trying to assign base class object into child class which is being treated as error.
Considering the size of codebase it is not feasible to typecast all the occurrences.

Is there any flag through which I can disable this kind of errors in clag?

Comment: There's a reason it errors out, the best thing to do is to fix them.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can do is `clang++ --std=c++98 -fpermissive`.

Comment: while compiling with gcc -fpermissive it  brings down the error to warning but it does not work with clang++. I am getting same error with clang++.

Comment: @AbhayKumar Did you manage to make errors into just warnings for Clang?